# How text editor Syntax Highlighting works?

Tags: text, syntax, syntax-highlighting, text-editor

I would like to implement a text editor with syntax highlighting, how the syntax highlighting magic works behind the scene, what is the algorithm behind? Is there any free library for doing this? Also, what is the ideas behind? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Lexical analyser processes the text, reducing it into tokens.
       Usually lexers for syntax highlighters are generated.
2. Text editor highlights the tokens